# Ajax.BeginForm cannot submit dropdown list selected value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, ajax.beginform

Form:

```
<div id="_SearchTab">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("searchResult", "Maintenance", null, 
        new AjaxOptions {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "gridArea",
            HttpMethod = "Get",
            LoadingElementId = "loading"
        }, new { id = "searchByCriteria"}))
{
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UNIT_CD)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UNIT_CD, new SelectList(ViewBag.UnitList, "Value", "Text"), "-- Select a Unit --")
    </td> </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PROGRAM_CD)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PROGRAM_CD)
        </td> </tr>

       </table>
            <div id=" buttonHolder">
    <input id="Search" type="Submit" value="Search"/>
</div>
} 
</div>
<div id="gridArea">
   display data here
</div>
```

searchResult action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult searchResult(string unitCode, string programCode) // showed both null in debug mode
        {
            // typical Linq stuff, if parameters are null, show all the data in the partial view, if at leastone of the parameters is not null, use it as search criteria
        }
```

The problem is when I submit the form, `searchResult` action's both parameters show `null`. I have tried multiple approaches including these below:

```
<input id="Search" type="Submit" value="Search" 
onclick="javascript:$('searchByCriteria').submit()" />
```

And this: (with Javascript runtime error)

```
<input id="Search" type="Submit" value="Search" 
onclick ="@(Url.Action("searchResult", "Maintenance", new { unitCode = Model.UNIT_CD, programCode = Model.PROGRAM_CD})) "/>
```

And adding `onsubmit=return searchForm()` to the form parameters, and use Javascript to submit:

```
function searchForm() { 
    $("#gridArea").html("");
            // Load SearchResult partialview in gridArea div
            $("#gridArea").load(
                '@(Url.Action("searchResult", "Maintenance", new { unitCode = Model.UNIT_CD, programCode = Model.PROGRAM_CD}))'
                )
            return false;
}
```

And jQuery functions for either `Search` button's click event,

```
$("#Search").click(
            function () {
                // clear the grid area
                $("#gridArea").html("");
                // Load SearchResult partialview in gridArea div
                $("#gridArea").load(
                    '@(Url.Action("searchResult", "Maintenance", new { unitCode = Model.UNIT_CD, programCode = Model.PROGRAM_CD}))'
                )
        });
```

or the form's submit event

```
$("#searchByCriteria").submit(function (event) {
            $("#gridArea").html("");
            $("#gridArea").load(
                '@(Url.Action("searchResult", "Maintenance", new { unitCode = Model.UNIT_CD, programCode = Model.PROGRAM_CD}))'
                )
        });
```

None of the above can pass parameters to the controller. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Your dropdownlist is named `UNIT_CD` so the parameter needs to be `string UNIT_CD`. And you dont have a form control named `programCode`

Comment: sorry `programCode` is a textbox. Let me add it in the code

Comment: Then the parameters needs to be `string UNIT_CD, string PROGRAM_CD` (to match the `name` attributes of the form controls

Comment: I renamed both parameters. Does not work

Comment: Of course it does. And as for your other attempts - `@Url.Action()` is razor code which is evaluated on the server before you pass it to the view, so the parameters your adding are the initial values of your model (i.e. `null`). It would need to be `.load('@Url.Action("searchResult", "Maintenance")', { unitCode: $('UNIT_CD').val(), programCode: $('#PROGRAM_CD').val() })` if you were to keep the original parameter names

Comment: `$('UNIT_CD).val()` or `$(#UNIT_CD).val()`?

Comment: Oops (typo) - yes its `$('#UNIT_CD).val()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114394/discussion-between-dylan-chensky-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

Might be you already got the solution. though you can go this way also,

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult searchResult(string unitCode, string programCode)
{
    unitCode= Request.Form["UNIT_CD"];
    programCode= Request.Form["PROGRAM_CD"];
    ...
}
```